# Ruby complex strings array to array of float

Tags: arrays, ruby, flatten

I'm trying to convert this (rather complex) string array of float strings into an array of float with no luck:

```
[  5.85142857   6.10684807   6.15328798   6.31582766   6.96598639
   7.61614512   7.87156463   8.73070295   9.38086168   9.65950113
  10.51863946  12.07437642  12.32979592  13.39791383  13.63011338
  13.86231293  14.09451247  14.72145125  14.97687075  15.85922902 ]
```

What I have tried:

```
  def onset_string_to_array(onset)
    # Remove the brackets.
    onset = onset.tr('[]', '')
    # Strip whitespace.
    onset = onset.strip
    # Split by newline character.
    onset_lines = onset.split("\n")
    # loop through each line.
    onset_array = []
    onset_array.push *onset_lines.map do |line|
      # Split by space character.
      line_array = line.split
      # Return one float per line.
      line_array.map(&:to_f)
    end
    onset_array
  end
```

Got me this:

```
[
  "0.53405896   0.7662585    0.99845805   1.20743764   1.41641723",
  "   1.64861678   1.85759637   2.32199546   3.43655329   3.57587302",
  "   4.08671202   4.7600907    4.99229025   5.87464853   6.52480726",
  "   6.78022676   7.66258503   8.33596372   9.4737415   10.12390023",
  "  10.35609977  10.750839    11.2152381   11.88861678  12.14403628",
  "  12.60843537  12.84063492  13.04961451  13.69977324  13.95519274",
  "  14.11773243  14.58213152  14.79111111  15.4644898   15.69668934",
  "  16.60226757  17.27564626  17.5078458   18.39020408  19.06358277",
  ## More lines...
  " 126.54875283 127.45433107 129.03328798 129.21904762 130.77478458",
  " 131.00698413 131.86612245 132.81814059 133.35219955 134.55963719",
  " 135.14013605"
]
```

What I want to get:

```
[ 0.53405896, 0.7662585, 0.99845805, 1.20743764, 1.41641723, 1.64861678, ...]
```

Any clue?

Comment: Sorry, what? You have that text and you're trying to parse it into array? What does flattening have to do with it? It looks pretty flat to start with; if anything it looks like you're trying to make it more deeply nested in your code...

Tell us: what you want the result to look like, and what you're getting instead, and be precise!

Comment: That's not a valid Ruby object. Show quotes where appropriate. When giving an example always show the desired result. For one, it's not clear if you want to end up with, for example, `"10.51863946"` (string) or `10.51863946` (float).

Comment: "no luck" is not a precise enough problem description for us to help you. *What* doesn't work? *How* doesn't it work? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ?

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/ https://idownvotedbecau.se/noexceptiondetails/

Comment: I have mistaken the meaning of flattening. Just want to save an array of float numbers there.

Comment: @CarySwoveland It's a string result from a python script that I wrote. The idea is to parse it into an array of float.

Comment: My point is that `[  5.85142857   6.10684807 ]` is not a Ruby object. `"[  5.85142857   6.10684807 ]"`, `'[  5.85142857   6.10684807 ]'`, `[  5.85142857,   6.10684807 ]` and `[  "5.85142857",   "6.10684807" ]` are all Ruby objects. Don't go with "you know that I mean it's a string" when you can be clear by just using the correct syntax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To parse this string you can:

```rb
onset.delete('[]').split.map(&:to_f)
```

(1) Firstly [delete](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/master/String.html#method-i-delete) brackets, (2) then [split](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/master/String.html#method-i-split) string to substrings by spaces and (3) finally convert to floats

```rb
onset =
  '[  5.85142857   6.10684807   6.15328798   6.31582766   6.96598639
      7.61614512   7.87156463   8.73070295   9.38086168   9.65950113
     10.51863946  12.07437642  12.32979592  13.39791383  13.63011338
     13.86231293  14.09451247  14.72145125  14.97687075  15.85922902 ]'

onset.delete('[]').split.map(&:to_f)
# => 
# [5.85142857,
#  6.10684807,
#  6.15328798,
#  6.31582766,
#  6.96598639,
#  7.61614512,
#  7.87156463,
#  8.73070295,
#  9.38086168,
#  9.65950113,
#  10.51863946,
#  12.07437642,
#  12.32979592,
#  13.39791383,
#  13.63011338,
#  13.86231293,
#  14.09451247,
#  14.72145125,
#  14.97687075,
#  15.85922902]
```

---

BTW Ruby has built-in method to get lines from the string, you don't need split it by new line character, just use `string.lines`

Comment: To be clear, `.split` with no arguments (and default `$;`) splits on sequences ("runs") of any type of whitespace, not just the space character. Which is what you want here, treating newlines and space characters and mixtures thereof as a single thing to split on, rather than getting empty strings between components, or splitting on just space or just newline.

Comment: `onset[1..-2]` is an alternative to `onset.delete('[]')...`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I initially thought about it, but we don't know how this structure looks, who knows may be `  ]  ` in the end. So for some reason I сhanged my mind and decided to `delete` instead of preliminary `strip` like `onset.strip[1..-2].split.map(&:to_f)`

Comment: "So for some reason I сhanged my mind..." is something I do regularly, often irrationally...

Answer (score 1):

I assume

```
str = "[  5.85142857   6.10684807   6.15328798   6.31582766   6.96598639\n  7.61614512   7.87156463   8.73070295   9.38086168   9.65950113\n  10.51863946  12.07437642  12.32979592  13.39791383  13.63011338\n  13.86231293  14.09451247  14.72145125  14.97687075  15.85922902 ]".
```

In which case you can write

```
str.lines.map { |line| line.scan(/\d+\.\d+/).map(&:to_f) }
  #=> [[ 5.85142857,  6.10684807,  6.15328798,  6.31582766,  6.96598639],
  #    [ 7.61614512,  7.87156463,  8.73070295,  9.38086168,  9.65950113],
  #    [10.51863946, 12.07437642, 12.32979592, 13.39791383, 13.63011338],
  #    [13.86231293, 14.09451247, 14.72145125, 14.97687075, 15.85922902]]
```

When, for example,

```
line = "10.51863946, 12.07437642, 12.32979592, 13.39791383, 13.63011338"
```

then

```
arr = line.scan(/\d+\.\d+/)
  #=> ["10.51863946", "12.07437642", "12.32979592", "13.39791383", "13.63011338"]
arr.map(&:to_f)
  #=> [10.51863946, 12.07437642, 12.32979592, 13.39791383, 13.63011338]
```

---

If by "flatten" you mean you wish to produce an array of 20 floats, rather than array of four arrays of five floats each (as above), you may write

```
str.scan(/\d+\.\d+/).map(&:to_f)
  #=> [ 5.85142857,  6.10684807,  6.15328798,  6.31582766,  6.96598639,
  #     7.61614512,  7.87156463,  8.73070295,  9.38086168,  9.65950113,
  #    10.51863946, 12.07437642, 12.32979592, 13.39791383, 13.63011338,
  #    13.86231293, 14.09451247, 14.72145125, 14.97687075, 15.85922902]
```

Comment: If not all of the numbers have decimal places, you may want to make the `\.\d+` part of the regular expression optional.

Comment: Thanks, @Chris, could do but, given the example, an integer mixed in with the floats (i.e., string representations thereof) could be bad data, so with what I have I'd not flag it and changing as you suggest would treat bad as good. Lose both ways. More to be done in a real app.

Answer (score 0):

You've stipped the `[]` off and stripped leading/traling whitespace, but after that you've gone down an unnecessarily complex path.

Just call `split`, by default it will greedily match runs of whitespace as its delimiter:

```
str = '[  5.85142857   6.10684807   6.15328798   6.31582766   6.96598639
   7.61614512   7.87156463   8.73070295   9.38086168   9.65950113
  10.51863946  12.07437642  12.32979592  13.39791383  13.63011338
  13.86231293  14.09451247  14.72145125  14.97687075  15.85922902 ]'

str.tr('[]', '').strip.split.map(&:to_f)
```

As to why your code is failing, you're splatting an array of arrays onto your initial array, meaning you never actually flatten it.

If, for some reason you had to avoid splitting the whole string by regex, and instead split it line-by-line, you should skip the `array.push(*other_array.map)` and just use `flat_map`:

```
str = '5.85142857   6.10684807   6.15328798   6.31582766   6.96598639
   7.61614512   7.87156463   8.73070295   9.38086168   9.65950113
  10.51863946  12.07437642  12.32979592  13.39791383  13.63011338
  13.86231293  14.09451247  14.72145125  14.97687075  15.85922902'

str.lines.flat_map { |line| line.split.map(&:to_f) }
```

Either option will produce the flat list of floats you're after:

```
[5.85142857,
 6.10684807,
 6.15328798,
 6.31582766,
 6.96598639,
 7.61614512,
 7.87156463,
 8.73070295,
 9.38086168,
 9.65950113,
 10.51863946,
 12.07437642,
 12.32979592,
 13.39791383,
 13.63011338,
 13.86231293,
 14.09451247,
 14.72145125,
 14.97687075,
 15.85922902]
```

Comment: Or `str.scan(/\d+\.\d+/).map(&:to_f)`

Comment: @engineersmnky Either way. Splitting on whitespace requires a less complicated regex and accounts for `1`, `.1`, `-1.0` and `1e6` without having to produce a progressively more complicated regex.

Comment: You shouldn't need a regex at all here. `.split(/\s+/)` could become `.split` (assuming no one is messing around with `$;`), or if you want to protect against messing around with `$;`, `.split(' ')`. Ruby differs from Python here; if you do a no-limit `split` and the separator to split on is `' '`, it splits on runs of whitespace (where Python differentiates between `.split()` and `.split(' ')`, with only the former getting the special runs-of-whitespace treatment).

Comment: @ShadowRanger You're right, of course. Should have tried that, but it's pretty non-obvious behaviour coming from almost any other language.

Comment: @user229044: Yeah, I ran into `.split` is the same as `.split(' ')` earlier today, and it was... quite surprising. Having no argument behave as "split on runs of whitespace", not that unintuitive (even if it is inconsistent with behaviors for explicit delimiters, as in Python), but having `.split(' ')` behave the *same* way, splitting on things that aren't the space character specifically? Very weird choice.

Comment: It's well known feature. Glad  that TYL

Comment: @ShadowRanger `split`'s default argument being `' '` makes sense to me, the surprise is that it works across *all* white space, not just spaces. `"a\n\n\nb".split(' ')` producing `['a', 'b']` is extremely surprising to me. I had though you would need a regex for that, but it appears `split(' ')` is more or less equivalent to matching `/\s+/`.